# Não consigo fazer comparação com números aleatórios

Tags: java

meu colegas boa noite,  eu  fiz um  jogo de matemático.
os números aleatório consigo mostrar ele na interface, mais ele não faz a comparação do numero do usuário com os resultados programados
eu  não consigo fazer comparação.
Se eu colocar o numero somente para aparecer na tela , ele sortei o numero , mas no console não.

```
private void verificarResultadoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){ 
    Random rand = new Random();
    int numero1 = rand.nextInt(2)+2 ;
    int numero2 = rand.nextInt(9)+2 ;
    int resultprogramado = (numero1*numero2);
    int respUsuario = Integer.parseInt(respostaUsuario.getText());

    if ( respUsuario == resultprogramado) {
        System.out.printf("Resposta certa!%n  %d x %d = %d", numero1, numero2, (numero1 * numero2));   
    } else {
        System.out.printf("Resposta errada!%n  %d x %d = %d", numero1, numero2, (numero1 * numero2)); 
    }
    gerarNovaOperacao();
}

private void gerarNovaOperacao() {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int numero1 = rand.nextInt(2)+2 ;
    int numero2 = rand.nextInt(9)+2 ;
    int resultprogramado = numero1 * numero2;
    telaX.setText(numero1+ "x" +numero2);
    respostaUsuario.setText("");
    respostaUsuario.requestFocus();

}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

```
//O Erro esta aqui, você ta comparando um tipo primitivo com um objeto;
if ( respUsuario == resultprogramado)
```

Soluções:

```
//intValue() vai retorno um tipo primitivo   
if(respUsuario.intValue() == resultprogramado)

//você ta usando equals ira fazer uma comparação de objeto
if(respUsuario.equals(new Integer(resultprogramado)))
```

Comment: Uma pequena otimização: em vez de `new Integer(resultprogramado)` prefira `Integer.valueOf(resultprogramado)`.